# Copying files cross the network

Tags: windows-7, networking, file-transfer, copy-paste

Two computer is connected via network cable. Comp A and CompB. CompA has 2 GB RAM and CompB has 4 GB RAM. I am trying to copy 50GB data(1 file not many files) from CompB to CompA.

1. Make the folder shared which contains the file in Comp B and copy from CompA
2. Create a shared folder in CompA and paste it from CompB to that shared folder.

Question is which operation works faster? or they are same?

Comment: the operations are approximately equivalent.

Comment: can I ask why down vote for?

Answer (score 1):

I just recently did some research on efficient transferring of large files in Windows.  Technically speaking, you should not have any issues cutting and pasting the file.

However, if you want to do it as fast as possible, you should be sure to disable any anti-virus programs on both machines.  In my tests, on transferring 350GB files, the AV program on both machines was a big bottleneck when dealing with large files.  Also, cut and paste is not necessarily the most efficient when copying large files.  A program that supports unbuffered I/O will copy more efficiently.  Microsoft's RichCopy is much faster than cut and paste.  You can get a copy [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproperf/thread/33971726-eeb7-4452-bebf-02ed6518743e/).  There are other programs out there that do unbuffered I/O copies, too.  Lastly, it appears that pushing from the source to a destination is slightly more reliable than the other way around according to this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2010/05/10/how-to-copy-very-large-files-across-a-slow-or-unreliable-network.aspx) from MS.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but I believe it would be same either way. [Note Mark Russinovich's article regarding the File IO and Cache Manager engine.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/02/04/2826167.aspx) It mentions how a remote file copy uses the Cache Manager (or in this case, doesn't use it).  So rather than filling up the system's memory with data only used for that one operation, remote file copy speeds were improved through changes in the network protocol.